# Taking thrift files from an API, and building the .NET dll file

Tags: c#, .net, thrift

I can't figure out how to compile thrift files for C#. I've read, "thrift files which can then be compiled down to language-specific interfaces for a wide variety of different programming platforms (Java, PHP, C/C++, Cocoa, Perl, C#, Ruby, etc.)."

I was looking here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/08/29/c-thrift-examples/ and it's like I have to compile the compiler, and then build the C# version from the thrift files provided.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right, you first compile the Win32 compiler using a [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) environment and then in turn use that compiler to create Thrift language interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can download thrift compiler executable from 
http://thrift.apache.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I was searching your question and I found [this useful topic](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/how-to-generate-cassandra-0-8-1-thrift-api/). May this helping :)